# Reestablishing expected behavior of cursor in QTextEdit following a dropEvent

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I wrote a class CustomTextEdit inheriting from qTextEdit and overriding the following two methods:

- `bool canInsertFromMimeData(const QMimeData *source) const override;`
- `void dropEvent(QDropEvent *e) override;`

so that it is possible to use the widget as the destination of a drag-and-drop action.

This has unexpected consequences on the behavior of the text cursor in this widget.

Before any `dropEvent`, it is possible to visually see where the text cursor is placed.
The text cursor position moves to the last place where the mouse has been clicked.
This is the expected behavior of the cursor.

Following the execution of the `dropEvent`, the vertical bar rendering of the text cursor
remains positioned after the inserted text. The text cursor no longer moves to the position
of the last click in the `QTextEdit` area.

If other `dropEvent`s are executed, several vertical bars may end up being displayed.

What is the correct procedure to reestablish the default behavior of the text cursor after
execution of a `dropEvent`?

Even the following definition of the `dropEvent` method produces this strange behavior:

```
void CustomTextEdit::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    this->insertPlainText(QString("<<dropped text>>"));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `update()` to trigger repaint? Because that sounds like a drawing glitch.

Comment: I did not try this. But unfortunately that does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution has been to explicitly set the text cursor before inserting the text, and to call the `dropEvent` method on the parent class `QTextEdit`.

```
void CustomTextEdit::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    // setting the text cursor
    QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
    cursor.setPosition(cursorForPosition(e->pos()).position());
    this->setTextCursor(cursor);
    // dropping the text
    this->insertPlainText(QString("<<dropped text>>"));
    // conclude the call by calling the parent method
    QTextEdit::dropEvent(e);
}
```